# Speed-up maven-deploy-plugin:deploy-file by comparing timestamps

Tags: bash, maven

I have a Maven project which depends on a large number of Ant projects, amongst others. I deploy all local jars possible of these dependencies into a single maven repo with this Bash script:

```
set -e
while IFS= read -r jarPath; do \
    mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile="$file" -DgroupId=${groupId} -DartifactId=$(basename "$jarPath") -Dversion=${version} -Dpackaging=jar -Durl=file:./repo/ -DrepositoryId=repo -DupdateReleaseInfo=true \
;done < list.txt
set +e
```

The script is executed every time these dependencies are rebuilt. The problem is, it takes together minutes of execution time for these effectively tenths of `mvn deploy:deploy-file` commands, even if normally there are only few jars or none which require an update.

Can Maven deploy only files with newer file stamps? I cannot see a relevant option in [its docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7/deploy-file-mojo.html). If there is no such possibility, can the analogous condition be implemented in the script as some Bash condition?

Each jar named `${jarPath}` ends up as `./repo/${groupId with each '.' replaced by '/'}/${file}/${version}/${file}-${version}.jar` where
`$file=$(basename "$jarPath")` is a filename with the extension `.jar`. It contains only basic ASCII letters, digits, '-' and '.'. No special characters like spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP=some.group.id
VERSION=0.0.1
REPO=repo

set -e
while IFS= read -r jarPath; do \
        F=$(basename "$jarPath")
        P=./${REPO}/$(echo ${GROUP} | tr '\.' '\/')/${F}/${VERSION}/${F}-${VERSION}.jar
        [ "$jarPath" -nt ${P} ] && mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile="$jarPath" -DgroupId=${GROUP} -DartifactId=${F} 
done < list.txt
set +e
```